# ¿Como refrescar un elemento N minutos en un Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Tengo una lista de objetos con un campo que muestra la fecha transcurrida, es decir "ahora mismo" "hace 1 minuto" "hace 2 minutos" etc...

Quien le interese es la siguiente: https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/TimeAgo

Ahora lo computo en `onBindViewHolder` del adapter, pero claro solo se refresca si el usuario está moviendo por la lista.

Lo que quiero es que cada minuto refresca todos los campos fecha, pero solo los que estén visibles.

Comment: ME estoy mirando https://github.com/Manikkumar1988/TimerInRecyclerView

Comment: Componente TextView con tiempo transcurrido https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago/blob/master/android-ago/src/com/github/curioustechizen/ago/RelativeTimeTextView.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edición

Buscando más soluciones que no acaban de funcionar bien, ya que crean fugas de memoria etc.. he encontrado ese componente https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago Funciona perfectamente en un recyclerview, falta comprobación de sobrecarga de items 1000 items para determinar si va fino o no.

**Su implementación:**

```
<com.github.curioustechizen.ago.RelativeTimeTextView
    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:relative_time_prefix="Completed "
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_primary" />
```

Asignación de un tiempo previo en guardado `onBindViewHolder`

```
if (item.getLastChecked() != null)
    holder.mSummary.setReferenceTime(item.getLastChecked().getTime());
else
   //sin tiempo especificado
```

#### Anterior

Siguiendo ese ejemplo: https://github.com/Manikkumar1988/TimerInRecyclerView

He creado una clase `UpdateTimerThread` que implementa `Runnable`

```
public class UpdateTimerThread implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = UpdateTimerThread.class.getSimpleName();

    public TextView holder;
    Handler handler;

    public UpdateTimerThread(Handler handler, TextView holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CREATE UpdateTimerThread: ");
        this.handler = handler;
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
        Date date = new Date();
        String stringDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
        holder.setText(stringDate);

        Log.d(TAG, stringDate);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}
```

Luego en la asignación del `ViewHolder` es donde se inicia el contador

```
public class SimpleListAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
...
private Handler handler = new Handler();
...

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
...
UpdateTimerThread customRunnable;
...
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    customRunnable = new UpdateTimerThread(handler,mSummary);
    handler.postDelayed(customRunnable, 100);
}
```

Crear función para finalizar los contadores al pausar la actividad

```
    public void clearAll() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

En el Activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mAdapter.clearAll();
}
```

> Problemas que detecto: que ejecuta un hilo por cada elemento que se visualice, sin hace caso que si se destruye pare el contador, es decir si tienes 1000 items y vas recorriendo por la lista, se ejecuta un hilo para cada item que se ha mostrado, solo cuando giras el terminal es cuando los elimina.
>   Si se elimina un item, pues sigue allí su hilo de ejecutación